# Get Application base URL dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I am calling an `API` with endpoint `http://localhost:8080/api/something..` using `axios` in `development` mode, now the end point is deployed to `https://www.myapp.com/api/something`, in future this end point's `base url` may change. So how can i set the `base url` dynamically?

Comment: What is `base url`?

Comment: like `http://localhost:8080` this is local url and this is `https://www.myapp.com` production url

Answer (score 2):

You should create an axios instance:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Then you use the instance normally like this:

```
const data = await instance.get("api/something..")
```

In order to set the base url, you can use [Enviromental Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). and set it like this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

For different deployment environments, you create different files. for instance for your staging environment, you create a `.env.staging` file and write:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://api.staging
```

For the production environment, you create a `.env.production` and write in it:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://api.production
```

Comment: so should i change this `baseURL` everytime? i mean for `dev` mode and for `production` mode separately?

Comment: @bakar_dev No. you need to use `env variables`. read my answer (and the linked resource) again since I edited it just before you submitted your comment. if have you any other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: i have set `REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https"//www.myapp.com` , what if the endpoint is deployed to some other url may be `https://www.mayapp2.com` after some days?

Comment: when creating a production build (npm run build), this value is populated with the current env variable by the time i run the build.   Is there a way to make the value to be populated dynamically? i.e. by the time i serve the build, it should check for the env var and use the value